# How to disable autoclosing of a dialog-based MFC application in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, dialog

When I start the program, I get the dialog and everything. But it closes by itself after some 10 seconds. How do I disable that?

EDIT: This happens when I run "Debug -> Start Without Debugging". This is the only way I know how to run the program.

EDIT2: My dialog is inheriting from `CDialogEx`.

Comment: There's something in your code that's making it close. There's no way to "disable" it. You have to fix your bug. I mean, "autoclose after N seconds" is not a standard feature of a dialog based MFC application, and there's no flag or style to enable or disable it.

Comment: Yes it is. When you create a new dialog-based application in Visual Studio, and you run "Debug -> Start Without Debugging", it closes by itself like I described.

Comment: I've never seen that happen, and I've used VS6, 2003, 2005 and 2008. I'm quite confident it doesn't happen in VS2010 or 2012 either, but I can't be 100% sure. Anyway, I've just made a test app, and hit "start without debugging", and you know what?, it doesn't close. So you have something that makes it close. It can be a bug in the code, configuration issues, problems with your OS, some other app making it close... But MFC apps don't close by themselves.

Comment: I'll second @MikMik's assertion. This isn't a Visual Studio or MFC feature. If your program is closing after ten seconds and you haven't coded it to do so, you've got a bug somewhere which is causing it to crash after that time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Confirmed, this happens with Visual Studio 2010, and doesn't happen with Visual Studio 2008. That means all the negative votes were completely unnecessary. It's a default of Visual Studio 2010, I didn't change anything. Nor did I make any bug, because I explicitly said that I created a new application without changing anything.

Thanks for all the negative votes.

Comment: You failed to identify the problem and provided a wrong answer blaming Visual Studio in unexpected behavior. The actual reason is a bug in code.

Comment: Notice that no one confirmed it doesn't happen in VS 2010. The commenter to the original post said he didn't try it in 2010.

Comment: @janko-m I kind of confirmed that it doesn't happen with Visual Studio 2010. Like all others noted, this doesn't seem to be a problem with Visual Studio. More likely a problem with the particular setup matija is using (some 'productivity' tool running in the background, outdate/misconfigured build environment, replaced the default MFC project template with a 'pimped' one, VS installation on top of a preview installation without first uninstalling it, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If your dialog is not modal, i.e. you are not firing it up using the DoModal() member function, it is possible that it is being created with the constructor, and deleted with the destructor as it goes out of scope.  You see this type of behaviour with some implementations of splash screens.  To figure out what is happening, put a breakpoint on your dialogs destructor, and look at the call stack that is leading to it.  It is also worth turning on all exceptions in the debugger, as you could be getting hit with an uncaught exception that is terminating your app.

As others have already said, this is not normal behaviour for an MFC app.

Answer (score 0):

Usually dialogs do not behave that way.

But in default, they close on OnOk (CDialog::OnOk) which is "Enter Key Pressed"
and OnCancel (CDialog::OnCancel()) which is "Esc Key Pressed"

Try overloading those two in your Dialog, to see if those get called and to handle
the behaviour there as you like it.

Perhaps the Close event should also be handled or watched.

here are lots of examples of what can be done with a Dialog (especially OnOk, OnCancel and Close) [CDialog Examples](http://aclacl.brinkster.net/MFC/ch08b.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with Visual Studio 2013:

I was creating the most basic MFC application with the Visual Studio wizard (either dialog-based, Single/Multiple document based), and just recompiling the generated code. No modification to the code at all.

I just **found out** that the "restart" does not occur when I **turn off my Anti-virus.** :-)
This is not a bug in Visual Studio, it is an environment problem.

My anti-virus is `Avast`.

**The solution for `Avast` is to turn-off the Deepscreen feature.**

> There, go to Settings / Active Protection / Deepscreen - and **disable** that.

More details could be found about this approach to the solution on Avast's forums, from this discussion:
https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=139935.0

Answer (score -3):

Just for the record, I tried this using Visual Studio 2010. I picked Dialog-based application and left all the other options at their default settings. Compiled both Debug and Release configurations, for x86 and x64. When launched using Start without Debugging none of the four executables terminated by themselves.

If this is happening for you I would assume you have some application running (in the background) that interferes with the expected behavior. Try setting up a virtual machine, install a clean Visual Studio and perform the same procedure again.